# Issue with Linq query in c#

Tags: c#, linq

Having an issue with the linq query, I'm trying to select the column names using the two conditions here. One is prefix and other is the length of prefix.

For ex my col names woulb be like  123_i 123_j 123_k 123_l 123a_i 123a_j 123a_k 123a_l

I have two prefixes here, one is 123 and other is 123a. My column name selection should look like:

prefix : 123   Columns : 123_i 123_j 123_k 123_l

prefix : 123a  Columns : 123a_i 123a_j 123a_k 123a_l

my linq query for the above logic is below:

```
   string[] columnnames = (from t in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                          where (t.ColumnName.Contains(prefix) && prefix.Length == 3)
                          ||(t.ColumnName.Contains(prefix) && prefix.Length == 4)
                          select t.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

The above code selects all the column names for prefix "123" rather than(123_i 123_j 123_k 123_l). I tried in debugging mode and checked the second part in the where condition is false. But still it selects all. I may be missing small thing here! Let me know how the OR in where works in Linq.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't your prefix be 123_, not just 123 (same of 123a_)? Your prefix lengths are then 4 and 5

Comment: crunchy - I don't think tht is the issue here. The code selects the column names properly, but where condition is not working correctly here.

Comment: To check for a prefix you should also use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`.

Comment: @Sri - I _do_ think that is the issue. 123a_i and 123_i _both_ contain `123`, so _both_ get selected when you select for prefix `123`. That the second part of your `where` is false is irrelevant as it is an OR condition. If the first part is true, the row gets returned. So look for `123_` or `123a_` as prefix and look at the results. Actually, looking for 123_, you need only _one_ where condition instead of two, and you do not need to check on prefix.length. The way you do it now will not work.

Comment: @Sri maybe i have misunderstood your question, but as it's stated, the first where clause will select all the column names as the will all contain the prefix. If that's not what is happening please post an example of expected, and actual results in the same format.

Comment: Oerkelens and crunchy - Thanks it worked after changing my prefix to 123_ and 123a_. also i didn't need check for the length!..thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always the `_` character this should work:

```
var contains = prefix + "_";

var names = (from t in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
             where t.ColumnName.Contains(contains)
             select t.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

or

```
var names = (from t in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
             where t.ColumnName.Contains(prefix + "_")
             select t.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it selects the prefix from the column name and them compares it.

```
 string[] columnnames = (from t in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                         where (t.ColumnName.Contains(prefix) && t.ColumnName.Split('_')[0] == prefix.Length)
                         select t.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

You could also probably remove *t.ColumnName.Contains(prefix)*